# Исключение java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File contains a path separator

Tags: java, android

После выполнения кода

```
private void saveFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+FILENAME, 0);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        osw.write(mEditText.getText().toString());
        osw.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Exception: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Происходит исключение

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File/storage/sdcard0/sample.txt
>   contains a path separator

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053487/illegalargumentexception-file-contains-a-path-separator-android

Comment: @Виктор Изменил код, теперь появляется исключение 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/test.txt: open failed: EISDIR(Is a directory)
Но мне не надо открывать файл

Comment: ну честно, вы пробовали использовать гугл? Вбиваете текст исключения и выскакивает с десяток таких же вопросов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339673/fileoutputstream-crashes-with-open-failed-eisdir-is-a-directory-error-when